# Extracting feature vectors from Inception V3 model

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Feature vectors are extracted from the "avg_pool" layer from an Inception V3 model. Do the feature vectors have different values if the extraction program is run on different machines/OS eg. Windows-64-bit and Ubuntu-64-bit?

Comment: To clarify, is this a saved graph you're re-loading and extracting weights from, or is training happening from scratch?

Comment: It is a saved model. I have the answer now, which is the feature vector values are the same across OS's as the math is the same. Thanks!